# How to make the indentifier "tortuga" not to be undefined?

Tags: c++

I want to create this function:

```
void drawSquare(int x) {
    tortuga.forward(x);
    tortuga.right(90);
    tortuga.forward(x);
    tortuga.right(90);
    tortuga.forward(x);
    tortuga.right(90);
}
```

However, I get that the identifier "tortuga" is undefined.

I tried to modify the function like this:

```
void drawSquare(int x) {
    ct::TurtleScreen scr;
    scr.bgcolor({ "white" });
    ct::Turtle tortuga(scr);
    Home(tortuga);
    tortuga.forward(x);
    tortuga.right(90);
    tortuga.forward(x);
    tortuga.right(90);
    tortuga.forward(x);
    tortuga.right(90);
    tortuga.pencolor({ "red" });
    tortuga.speed(ct::TS_FASTEST);
    scr.exitonclick();
}
```

I get that the identifier "tortuga" is defined now, which seems to work.However, 20ish windows appeared where in each window, the turtle only drew three sides of a square like the following image:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mXpN.png)
I expected a spiral to be drawn.

Here is all the program:

```
#include"CTurtle.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define Home(x) x.left(90)

namespace ct = cturtle;
int shellSize;
int initialShellSize;



void drawSquare(int x) {
    ct::TurtleScreen scr;
    scr.bgcolor({ "white" });
    ct::Turtle tortuga(scr);
    Home(tortuga);
    tortuga.forward(x);
    tortuga.right(90);
    tortuga.forward(x);
    tortuga.right(90);
    tortuga.forward(x);
    tortuga.right(90);
    tortuga.pencolor({ "red" });
    tortuga.speed(ct::TS_FASTEST);
    scr.exitonclick();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Type the size of the outershell of the spiral: "; // Type a number and press enter
    std::cin >> shellSize; // Get user input from the keyboard
    initialShellSize = shellSize;
    
    for (int i = 10; i <= initialShellSize; i = i + 10)
    {
        shellSize = initialShellSize - (initialShellSize/i);
        drawSquare(shellSize);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to define and initialise the turtle *outside* of the `drawSquare` function, and pass it into that function as a parameter.

Comment: Also if you want four sides of a square to be drawn then you need to call `forward` four times. I've never used this library before, but that seems fairly clear.

Comment: How do I initialize it? I use the Home(tortuga); to initialize it?

Comment: Move the screen and turtle declarations to `main` and pass the turtle object from main to your function (by reference presumably).

Comment: Here `ct::TurtleScreen scr; scr.bgcolor({ "white" }); ct::Turtle tortuga(scr);`

Comment: What do you mean by reference?

Comment: A [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) in C++ is an alias to an object or a function. It's similar to a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used this library before, but it seems all you need to do is add a turtle parameter to your function and pass the turtle object to the function. This is not dissimilar to what you've already done with the `x` parameter. Parameter passing is a basic technique of the C++ language (and pretty much any programming language).

```
void drawSquare(ct::Turtle& tortuga, int x) {
    Home(tortuga);
    tortuga.forward(x);
    tortuga.right(90);
    tortuga.forward(x);
    tortuga.right(90);
    tortuga.forward(x);
    tortuga.right(90);
    tortuga.forward(x);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Type the size of the outershell of the spiral: "; // Type a number and press enter
    std::cin >> shellSize; // Get user input from the keyboard
    initialShellSize = shellSize;
    
    ct::TurtleScreen scr;
    scr.bgcolor({ "white" });
    ct::Turtle tortuga(scr);
    for (int i = 10; i <= initialShellSize; i = i + 10)
    {
        shellSize = initialShellSize - (initialShellSize/i);
        drawSquare(tortuga, shellSize);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I've used a reference `ct::Turtle& tortuga` instead of `ct::Turtle tortuga`. I'm guessing that is right, but as I said I've never used this library before.

And as already mentioned to get a square I'm guessing you need to call `forward` four times.

I've also put the call to `Home` inside the function, you might disagree.

Comment: *'I expected a spiral to be drawn.'* – which would need to instead of drawing only 4h side restart drawing the three sides with forwarding distance a bit reduced – as many times as spiral rounds should appear...